# Encrypting a string in Unity3D C#, sending via HTTP GET request as a URL parameter, decrypting in node.js server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, unity-game-engine

I am using a very bubblegum-and-duct-tape solution for handling an online leaderboard for a small arcade-style game in Unity WebGL. Currently, the game client sends an HTTP GET request with two parameters `?name=NAME&score=111111` . While the URL will not be normally presented to the average player, obviously it is very easy to find and exploit via browser developer tools.

My solution was to somehow encrypt the score string with a key exclusive to the game client and server, and if the submitted string did not decrypt successfully, the server would reject the score.

However, I have absolutely zero understanding of cryptography, and my many attempts to google for solutions and adapting code from many results have all been futile. I have no idea which algorithm to use, whether my keys are actually usable, and why each thing isn't working. I have no idea how else to easily prevent this leaderboard from having false scores submitted, and this is the most viable solution I could think of.

How would I be able to decrypt a short string on the Unity end, pass it through the URL, and then decrypt it from the node.js end, and execute specific code based on whether it successfully decrypted or not?